# practicallity of having a single node cassandra multisitecluster(3 way)

Tags: cassandra, replication

Is it possible to put a Cassandra cluster with single node DC with 2 remote DC which is also having a single node assuming the replication factor is required to be 3 in this case? The remote cluster is in the same geographical area but not same building for HA. Or is there any hard rules that for high availability and consistency for a need for a local quorum node to achieve that?

Our setup may be smaller compared to big data and usually used to store time series data with approximately 2000/3000 (on different key) sampling per second.

Is there other implications other than read/write may be slow due to the comms delay?

Comment: disclaimer: I'm new to cassandra. what's a remote cluster? do you mean a single cluster with multiple DC's?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: btw, is this going to be deployed on aws?

Comment: yes for now which is in multiple AZ

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: I am new to cassandra.

Turns out I want to deploy a similar setup: 3 nodes on aws, each in its own AZ (But all in the same region). from what I read, this setup is just a *single* DC, with 3 nodes.

- You need to use Ec2Snitch to reduce the latency between your clients and the nodes.
- Using RF=3 provides you with the HA that you need, since every node has all the data
- Inter-AZ communication should be fairly fast. refer to this: http://highscalability.com/blog/2016/8/1/how-to-setup-a-highly-available-multi-az-cassandra-cluster-o.html
- becuase you'll be running in a single DC, local-quorum == quorum. so as long as you'll be writing to QUROUM (which requires 2/3 nodes (AZs) to be up), you'll be strongly consistent and HA.

Comment: edit: the ec2snitch doesn't really have any latency-reducing code. it just automatically splits up the nodes to racks correctly. you could achieve the same effect manually.